# Convert .doc to HTML error

Tags: java, android, doc

The following code works to convert a .doc-file to a HTML-file. But it only seems to work with doc-files including "normal" text. When trying to convert a .doc including text-properties as **Bold** and underlined it gives me error messages. How can this be fixed?

```
`public class ConvertDoc {

public void createHTML() throws Exception {

try {


        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard, "/MyFolder/myfile.doc");

        HWPFDocumentCore document = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(new FileInputStream(file));

        WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
        wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(document);

        Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
        out.close();

        String html = new String(out.toByteArray());


        BufferedWriter outstream = new BufferedWriter
                (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sdcard + "/MyFolder/myfile.html"), "UTF-8"));

        outstream.write(html);
        outstream.close();



    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }try`
```

**Error log:**

`10-24 04:57:32.651: E/dalvikvm(6011): Could not find class 'java.rmi.UnexpectedException', referenced from method org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySetFactory.create
10-24 04:57:32.651: W/dalvikvm(6011): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 384 (Ljava/rmi/UnexpectedException;) in Lorg/apache/poi/hpsf/PropertySetFactory;
10-24 04:57:32.651: D/dalvikvm(6011): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0020
10-24 04:57:32.661: D/dalvikvm(6011): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0848 at 0x26 in Lorg/apache/poi/hpsf/PropertySetFactory;.create
10-24 04:57:32.801: W/System.err(6011): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 04:57:32.811: W/System.err(6011):     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.AbstractWordUtils.compactChildNodesR(AbstractWordUtils.java:146)
10-24 04:57:32.811: W/System.err(6011):     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.WordToHtmlUtils.compactSpans(WordToHtmlUtils.java:238)
10-24 04:57:32.821: W/System.err(6011):     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.WordToHtmlConverter.processParagraph(WordToHtmlConverter.java:596)
10-24 04:57:32.821: W/System.err(6011):     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.AbstractWordConverter.processParagraphes(AbstractWordConverter.java:1113)
10-24 04:57:32.832: W/System.err(6011):     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.WordToHtmlConverter.processSingleSection(WordToHtmlConverter.java:617)
10-24 04:57:32.832: W/System.err(6011):     at org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.AbstractWordConverter.processDocument(AbstractWordConverter.java:722)`

Answer (score 0):

RMI based exception in propertySetFactory generates this errror.

As metioned on this http://poi.apache.org/changes.html link, "Avoid using RMI based exception from PropertySetFactory, as it's not needed nor helpful" is been fixed in Version 3.10-FINAL (2014-02-08).

Use, 3.10 Final or upper version to get rid of 'java.rmi.UnexpectedException' error.